# Remove warning message 'Found more than one class "tbl_df" in cache; using the first, from namespace 'tibble' Also defined by ‘memisc’

Tags: r, tibble

There seems to be a clash in the `tibble` and `memisc` packages causing the error message.

```
library(tibble)
library(memisc)
library(dplyr)

d <- tibble(value = seq(0, 100)) 

    Found more than one class "tbl_df" in cache; using the first, from namespace 'tibble'
Also defined by ‘memisc’
Found more than one class "tbl_df" in cache; using the first, from namespace 'tibble'
Also defined by ‘memisc’
Found more than one class "tbl_df" in cache; using the first, from namespace 'tibble'
Also defined by ‘memisc’
Found more than one class "tbl_df" in cache; using the first, from namespace 'tibble'
Also defined by ‘memisc’
Found more than one class "tbl_df" in cache; using the first, from namespace 'tibble'
Also defined by ‘memisc’
```

I tried simply detaching the `memisc` package but the warning remained. It is an extremely pernicious bug that comes up a LOT.

There are instructions how to squash the message [here](https://github.com/melff/memisc/issues/47) with the poster saying "Therefore, a potential fix could involve (1) removing the setOldClass("tbl_df") code and (2) updating the NAMESPACE file to import the tbl_df S4 class from the tibble R package. This would also require (3) listing the tibble R package under Imports and not Enhances in the DESCRIPTION file. What do you think?"

Now this make sense to some but not to me. Can anyone break down the steps involved to remove this bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug of the `memisc` package, this has been fixed in version 0.99.30.7, here is the [GitHub update of the library](https://github.com/melff/memisc/commit/d5ee76685e7f29c74c6dac332c89e201868630fa).

Also there was a GitHub issue about it [here](https://github.com/melff/memisc/issues/47).

Comment: Thanks U12-Forward. I ran the code you linked me to but I'm still getting the message.

Comment: @llewmills There is no way to solve this, problem, this only has been fixed in future versions, the creator of the `memisc` package fixed it in future versions

Comment: @llewmills You should just ignore this warning, or update the `memisc` package to a more recent version.

Comment: The warning is way too pernicious to ignore. For one thing it obscures error messages and makes them harder to spot. I downloaded memisc v0.99.30.7  from CRAN and tried `install.packages("~/Downloads/memisc_0.99.30.7.zip", repos = NULL, type="source")` but got the error `Warning: invalid package 'C:/Users/llewm/Documents/Downloads/memisc_0.99.30.7.zip'
Error: ERROR: no packages specified
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/llewm/Documents/Downloads/memisc_0.99.30.7.zip’ had non-zero exit status`. Nothing seems to be working for me today

Comment: @llewmills Oh sorry, wrong version, he only published that 4 days ago, try other version, like 0.99.28.0.1 or higher versions

Comment: No such thing, only 27 or 30, unless I'm missing something see  (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/memisc/index.html)

Comment: @llewmills But it is on GitHub, you should try it maybe?

Comment: Just went to gtihub, tried `devtools::install_github("melff/memisc",subdir="pkg")` as instructed and got `* installing *source* package 'memisc' ...
ERROR: cannot remove earlier installation, is it in use?` and a lot more. But it is not in use. I detached it. It's like a virus this bug.

Comment: @llewmills very strange. I suppose that you need to wait a few days until version 0.99.30.7 is out.

Comment: The developer of memisc is dreaming if they expect people to use their package when it clashes with the most popular suite of packages in R. So annoying! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @llewmills Yeah. He must of not test it. Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

@llewmills

1. I cannot fix a bug that I cannot reproduce. If I run the above code on R 4.1.1, I do not get any messages as shown above. Also, these are only informational messages, neither warnings nor errors.
2. The problems with installing the new package version arise from the fact that the package is still in use (i.e. still attached). Trying again with a pristine R session should work.
3. Please remember and respect that 'memisc' is a volunteer's work, and not a commercial product. I am sharing software that helps me very much in my own academic research, in the hope that it will help others as well.  Using it does not entitle you to any kind of 'customer service'.

Comment: My apologies. I was just a little cranky. The bug did indeed go away when I restarted my computer. I do not expect customer service and appreciate R and SO so much. My sincere apologies and I admire your ability to create a package at all.

Comment: No worries. The complex interaction of different packages with different APIs and different assumptions can indeed lead to sometimes frustrating results.

Comment: Also, the CRAN build system is occasionally a bit slow. This is why I provide Wind*ws binaries on my GitHub release page.